# vba Missing 0 when adding string and date

Tags: string, vba, date, excel

I am trying to post a string + date (Column B + Column C) to a cell.

```
B       | C
2600 HK | 09/29/2014
```

I tried using this code

```
'Merge Column B with Column C

Range("A1") = Range("B1") & " " & Range("C1")
```

However the result will become `2600 HK 9/29/2014` Instead of `2600 HK 09/29/2014`

I have already formatted column `C` as date format mm/dd/yyyy

How do I add that 0 back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be :

```
Range("A1") = Range("B1") & " " & Format(Range("C1").Value, "mm\/dd\/yyyy")
```

You have to escape the `/`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx for more details

Answer (score 1):

Date values in excel are stored internally as a number so the format of the cell doesn't really affect how VBA interprets that value. To get your date in the desired format try using the `Format()` function as below:

```
Range("A1") = Range("B1") & " " & Format(Range("C1"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Alternatively you could use Excel's TEXT function as part of a formula in cell A1 to the same effect, as below:

```
=B2&" "&TEXT(C2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: This may not work on some locales due to the way the `/` is processed.

Comment: @JustinJDavies The `/` character is the date separator character when used in this context, I understand it may be replaced by a different character in locales other than the OPs but I'd assume that was a **desirable** feature, not something to be avoided. It certainly won't cause the code to 'not work'.

Comment: You are correct. I guess the question is ambiguous because it doesn't clarify if it means a literal `/` or a `{dateseparator}`. My wording was too strong as I interpreted it only one way of a possible many interpretations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I never did VBA before so I am still  learning. Thank You.